# Efficient Pattern Matching / String Merging Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, similarity, knuth-morris-pratt

I'm looking for an Algorithm (Preferably with a java implementation) for merging Strings.

my problem is as following :

suppose I have an Array/List of Strings *{"myString1" , "my String1" , "my-String-1" ... }*
I'd like the algorithm to point out that there is a very high probability that 
all of these values denote the "**myString1**".

so I would like to compact my list.
maybe this can be done with KMP or maybe there is something more suitable.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define "high probably?"  Why does the string "myString2" not have a high probability of being the same as "myString1," even though "my string 1" does?  I think you need to be more precise with your terms and definitions in order to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: You want some fuzzy matching algorithm?

Comment: @templatetypedef you're correct, maybe I need to be more specific here.
but I assume that "myString2" is a bad match since it introduce the character "2". 
now I understand that algorithmic-wise there is no diff between introducing "2" and "-" , both are new characters. 
but looking at it human-wise there is a difference between "Terminator 1" , "Terminator-1" and "Terminator 2"

Comment: When you say : "very high probability", what do you mean? same characters? percent S of common characters? you have to be more specific

Comment: @barak1412, I'm trying , I really do :)

when I say high probability I mean over 90%, basically for my given problem I'd like the non alphabetic and numerical characters such as #,-,$,*,[space], etc.. to be viewed as disposable chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [Edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) is good heuristic for merging strings.

**EDIT:**

You can modify the edit distance algorithm:

You can give different value for d(-,c) for character c.

So in the following example: "String1","String2", you can "punish" the score but letting d(1,2) be high, in contrast to "String 1","String1" that won't be punished because the score will be d(-,' ').

Comment: I don't think this works here - it would report that "myString1" and "myString2" would be more similar than "myString1" and "my string 1."

Comment: He said the opposite. It is hard to answer his question without knowing what his definition for "very high probability".

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, [Approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) could be of some use. I dont believe KMP would suit the purpose, because it is designed for precise substring matching

Comment: thanks will look into it and report shortly.
is anyone familiar with [this](http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/) implementation?